# Prevent Googlebot from indexing a page while still allowing access

Tags: angularjs, robots.txt, googlebot

In a angularjs app, I'm using some fragment like `/fragments/welcome-1.html` which get displayed as a part of `/welcome`. I thought, I could exclude it from Google search via

```
Disallow: /fragments
```

in `robots.txt`, but it completely prevents any access by Googlebot and therefore the page `/welcome` can't be displayed correctly.

Obviously, I can't do this, but how can I ensure that Google can fetch the fragment and it won't index it? Note that it's no real HTML, just a part of the body, so I can't really use a `meta` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the [X-Robots-Tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) and I serve all pages from `/fragments` using

```
X-Robots-Tag: googlebot: noindex
```

Let's see if it really works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a angularjs issue or if can be resolve with angular. I had a similar problem with the bot. I have a folder that I host multiple websites. I resolve it in Google analytics console, after you validate and monitor your domain, there is an option on the menu called Google index in there's an option to removes URLs. Just put all the URLs that you dont want Google to index.

https://www.google.com/analytics/